# Handle Bootstrap Close Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I know this is an old question but I wonder if there is a callback for Bootstrap Modal close event that actually runs before the close event is processed by the 
browser. The modal usually closes before the contents destroy.

```
          $('#div').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
             var cropper = $('#ferret').imgAreaSelect({ remove : true});     
          });
```

The imageAreaSelect Components are not removed as quickly as the modal closes since it runs only after the modal closes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an event for when the hide method is called, before it is hidden:

> **hide.bs.modal** This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.

```
$('#div').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {...
```

See the [bootstrap modal events here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)